# How to execute PHP code to an uploaded pdf file?

Tags: php

I am working on extracting text of pdf files using PHP. I stumbled upon this code https://gist.github.com/neko-fire/7038322 but since I am pretty new to PHP, I'm not really sure how to actually execute the code?

I have already included

```
<?php include('class.pdf2text.php'); ?>
```

in my index.php file and here is the rest of the code:

```
<form id="upload">
    <input type="file" name="Upload" accept=".pdf" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -99" id="up">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("up").onchange = function() {
        <?php 
        $a = new PDF2Text();
        $a->setFilename('STMNT_RESULT.pdf');
        $a->decodePDF();
        echo $a->output();
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: use and xmlhttprequest instead

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have Javascript on the bottom when you're first testing it.

Create a .php file with the following code, then run the php file. Echo out the result to the browser.

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('replace this with your pdf filename.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

Once it's in working order, then do your UI magic =)